# record calls in asterisk withing dial() application

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to call 5 sip phones simultaneously and also i want to record call when it is connected to any of the sip phone.
my dialplan is :

`exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/user1&SIP/user2&SIP/user3&SIP/user4&SIP/user5,55,options)`

I m able to receive call but I tried many options and I am not able to record call .
I need to record call like callerid-reciverid-date.wav

Answer (score 3):

You can use MixMonitor to record calls

```
exten=> s,1,Set(Date=${STRFTIME(,EST4EDT,%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S)})
exten=> s,n,MixMonitor(${CALLERID(NUM)}-${EXTEN}_${Date}.WAV,W(1));
exten=> s,n,Dial(SIP/user1&SIP/user2&SIP/user3&SIP/user4&SIP/user5,55,options)
```

your recorded files usually are in /var/spool/asterisk/monitor

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also wanted to save file name with receiver number in it like 012245-user2-date.wav as i asked in my question . Now my work is done :D . I used Monitor instead of MixMonitor.